# Adobe Scout is not starting a new session for loaded SWFs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-development, adobe-scout

**I have an issue with Adobe Scout. It does not listen (doesn't start a new session like it should) for a SWF loaded by another (main) SWF.** The SWFs have advanced telemetry enabled and the setup is correct as described in http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started .html. Please help

I am using Win 7 64-bit, the latest versions of Adobe Scout and Flash Player, Chrome 32 / IE 11. Also I have made sure that the Scout server is listening, as descibed in the article linked above: *Verify that the Scout server listening. Open Scout, and then type localhost:7934 into your web browser. It should respond quickly with "server dropped connection", "no data received", or something similar (since Scout is not an HTTP server). Scout should show the error message "can't start a session because the telemetry data isn't valid". If the browser stalls for a long time, and then comes back with "server not found" or something similar, then the socket isn't working.*

Thank you

Comment: I believe a separate scout session is only started for a Worker SWF (separate threaded runtime instance).  I believe if you simply use a Loader, those telemetry data are included in your main session.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is correct

Comment: Added answer with link to reference.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This adobe article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/understanding-flashplayer-with-scout.html) states that:

> When you run Flash content in a web browser, Flash Player typically
>   runs in a separate operating system process. There's only one process
>   for all the SWFs running in that browser, including any related worker
>   threads, and Flash Player manages the execution of these SWFs so that
>   it looks like they're running independently. **Each running SWF is known
>   as a player instance, and this corresponds to a session in Scout.
>   Worker threads are player instances too.** For AIR content, there's only
>   one main player instance, plus any workers it uses

So separate scout sessions are started for Worker SWFs (separate runtime instance). If you simply use a Loader, those telemetry data are included in your main session.